# Looking to use an Op-Amp to scale a high-voltage system to a low voltage system

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-regulator

I am looking to scale a voltage of range 30V-120V to a 9V-14V range. I am looking into using an Op-Amp and have found that ideal Op-Amps use a system that cannot take a varying 3rd input as a constant to the proportion. Any help as to what I should do?

Comment: Can you express your desired result as a simple math equation (using +, -, x, /). If so then you can build an opamp circuit to perform the same sequence of operations.

Answer (score 2):

So you want linear scaling with 9V output when 30V input, and 14V output when 120V input, correct? Vout = (Vin * 5 / 90) + (22/3). My first thought was can you use a non-inverting configuration with the inverting input reference at 7.3V?

However can't get less than unity gain with non-inverting configuration. So take an inverting op amp configuration to get the 5/90 gain, then use a second stage to invert again and add the offset. The offset is a negative voltage because the second stage is an inverting adder.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6dDzr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can click on the link that says "simulate this circuit", and try it yourself.

Some caveats:

120V is a hazardous voltage, use appropriate precautions.

120VAC has peak voltages that are higher than the RMS average of 120Vrms, the actual peaks are almost +150V / -150V. For this simulation I assume you mean 120V DC not AC. Still hazardous though, so use sensible precautions.

The high voltage will be across R1 because node V1 is driven to virtual ground.

I'm assuming that the op amp is powered before the 30VDC..120VDC signal is present. The question requirements are a bit vague. If the 120VDC might be present before the op amp power supplies are stable, then it would be more robust to use a resistive divider first (since less than unity gain!) and then the summing amplifier.

This all gets a lot easier if there were a way to avoid the offset voltage, perhaps just use an ADC with a suitable resistor divider input. Hard to tell what's the best approach given the limited information. But there are definitely ways to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: Why don't you divide the input voltage with a resistive voltage divider ?  Having the op-amp input within its tolerances depends on its ability to maintain the 'virtual ground': If it is not powered before applying the high voltage, you will fry it.

Comment: @TEMLIB good idea; edited to incorporate resistive voltage divider input suggestion... also it occurs to me OP could just use resistive divider and then feed an ADC input...

Answer (score 0):

Is it an AC voltage?  (you could use a transformer to step it down.)

If you have to go down to DC, then can you put a resistor divider on the front end to get the voltage down to more "normal" opamp ranges.  (Connecting an opamp directly to 120 V is just asking to let the magic smoke out of the opamp... there are some high voltage opamps.  LTC6090 for one.)

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1yqci.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Applying Ohm's law :

- VO' = VO = (R3*R2*VI+R3*R1*VP) / (R1*R2+R3*R2+R3*R1)

There are three unknown (R1,R2,R3), with two references VI1,VO1 and VI2,VO2 two resistor values can be deduced :

- R2 * (VI1 * VO2 - VO1 * VI2) = R1 * VP * (VO1 - VO2)
- R3 * (VP * VI1 - VO2 * VI1 - VP * VO1 - VP * VI2 + VO1 * VI2 + VP * VO2) = R2 * (VO2 * VI1 - VO1 * VI2)

If we have :

- VI1=30V, VO1=9V
- VI2=130V, VO2=14V
- VP=15V (polarisation voltage)

We get :

- R2=R1*75/660
- R3=R1*75/615

The op-amp here is just a unity gain follower, it can be powered by the 15V polarisation voltage.

Precision depends on resistor values (which are non standard) and VP. Some calibration may be needed.

Expecting DC voltages

Warning : Hazardous voltage, yadda, yadda...